# cppcheck throws warning on const std::string[]

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I'm struggling with a warning that `cppcheck` (version 1.85 on a Linux machine) is reporting:

> someFile.h:23:29: warning: Redundant code: Found a statement that begins with string constant. [constStatement]
>   const std::string OffOn[]= {"off", "on"};
>                               ^

I did some research and found that changing the statement to

```
const std::string OffOn[]= {std::string("off"), std::string("on")};
```

removes the warning. However I do not understand what's going on, and what's "bad" about my first solution. Maybe someone can explain it to me? Or give me some hints!

Comment: Maybe it recomeds you to use initializer_list like: `const std::string OffOn[]{"off", "on"};`, so `=` is just unnecessary.

Comment: @DenisSablukov that's it! And now it make perfectly sense to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd actually file an issue report to cppcheck. The warning message produced is really unhelpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It recommends you use initialization with a *`braced-init-list`* like: `const std::string OffOn[]{"off", "on"};`, so `=` is just unnecessary.

Comment: It's probably nitpicking, but in this context `{...}` is not a `std::initializer_list`. It's a `braced-init-list`.

Comment: It's clearly a bug regardless; there's no "redundant code" here